# Stream RTSP over TCP

Tags: tcp, stream, vlc, rtsp, rtp

I am attempting to use VLC to restream the RTSP feed from an IP camera so that clients can access the VLC stream rather than the camera directly. I am completely open to alternatives other than VLC if there is software available that can host my RTSP feed.

The restream part in itself works fine, but I need the RTP data to be streamed over TCP rather than UDP and VLC seems to be defaulting to UDP no matter what types of commands I use.

You can see it here in the SDP header response from VLC that it will be sending the RTP information over UDP

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
Server: VLC/3.0.4
Date: Wed, 29 Apr 2020 13:02:56 GMT
Transport: RTP/AVP/UDP;unicast;client_port=50566-50567;server_port=50568-50569;ssrc=BBB7338A;mode=play

I have tried a multitude of commands in the streaming output options such as

:sout=#rtp{sdp=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/stream} :no-sout-all :sout-keep :rtsp-tcp :sout-rtp-proto=tcp

Any help or guidance in a different direction would be greatly appreciated.